# Автоматическое обновление datagridview - C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

Необходимо обновлять datagridview по изменению таблицы в БД. В ПО работают одновременно несколько человек, необходимо что если один делает изменение то и второй это сразу видел. Я думал создать таблицу и мониторить колво записей раз в 10 секунд например, если кто то что то делает параллельно делать в нее инсерт и если старое колво count не совпадает с новым то апдейтить datagridview, но такое решение мне кажется сильно нагрузить ПО и это выглядит сильным костылем. Возможно ли написать службу что бы она могла обновлять datagridview по состоянию БД?

Comment: Какая именно СУБД используется? Двух- или трёхзвенка? Пользователи и БД в локальной сети или...?

Comment: Двух- или трёхзвенка - это не совсем понял. БД MSSQL, пользователи и БД находятся в одной локальной сети.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для [получения изменений](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/62xk7953(v=vs.110).aspx) из SqlServer можно использовать класс [SqlDependency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency(v=vs.110).aspx).

Однако, не стоит создавать эту зависимость между СУБД и каждым клиентским приложением. У вас должен быть выделенный сервер приложений (то, что вы назвали службой), который будет получать уведомления об изменениях в SqlServer. И уже этот сервер приложений посылает сообщения об изменениях всем клиентам.

Ну а дальше, клиент, получив уведомление, обращается с запросом на получение новых данных.

Comment: БД стоит на выделенном сервере, ПО стоит у каждого пользователя на ПК. Как я понял мне нужно создать службу на сервере где БД, эта служба должна посылать запрос в каждое ПО и согласно этого запроса обновлять например datagridview.

Comment: @Winteriscoming - Примерно так, да.

Comment: Нет примера у Вас случайно, я новичок в C#, службу не разу не создавал, примерно понимаю как все будет, но если был бы какой то пример я бы его использовал как "мануал".